# Mass .htaccess URL Forwarding

Tags: redirect, htaccess

I'm doing the migration of a site, from MovableType to WordPress. The website contains around 3500 posts and when I uploaded the information to the new version of the site, the links have been altered.

Old site link (note that the category-name and the nodenumber are not fixed values. The nodenumber is a number that changes in each post):

http://websitename.com/category-name/nodenumber/title-of-the-post

New site link: http://websitename.com/category-name/title-of-the-post

My question is the following:

What would be the easiest and effective way to configure my Htaccess file to do a redirection from the old links to the new ones? There might be a simple way than to write them all by hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at the Redirection plugin? You could make a rewrite rule for something like this: `/([^\/]+/([1-9]+)/([^/]+)/?` and then have it redirect to `http://newsite.com/$1/$3`, or something along those lines at least. I think you could do this with `.htaccess` as well, but I'm not familiar enough with the format for it to give you code in good conscious.

Comment: Redirection plugin link: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/redirection/